# Reducing amout of lines in variable within loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a txt file containing 10000 lines. Each line is an ID.
Within every loop iteration I want to select 100 lines, put them in a special format and do something. I want to do this until the document is finished.
The txt looks like this:

```
406232C1331283
4062321N022075
4062321H316457
```

Current approach:

```
$liste = get-content "C:\x\input.txt"

foreach ($item in $liste) {

azcopy copy $source $target --include-pattern "*$item*" --recursive=true

}
```

The system will go throug the TXT file and make a copy request for every name it finds in the TXT file. Now the system is able to handle like 300 search-patterns in one request. like

```
azcopy copy $source $target --include-pattern "*id1*;*id2*;*id3*"
```

How can I extract 300 items from the document at once, separate them with semicolon and embedd them in wildcard? I tried to pipe everyting in a variable and work with -skip.
But it seems not easy to handle :(

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-ReadCount` parameter to `Get-Content` to send multiple lines down the pipeline:

```
Get-Content "C:\x\input.txt" -ReadCount 300 | ForEach-Object {

    $wildCards = ($_ | ForEach-Object { "*$_*" } -join ';'
    azcopy copy $source $target --include-pattern $wildCards --recursive=true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want 100 or 300 at a time?  ;-)
I'm not sure if I really got what the endgoal is but to slice a given amount of elements in chunks of a certain size you can use a for loop like this:

```
$liste = Get-Content -Path 'C:\x\input.txt'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Liste.Count; $i += 100) {
    $Liste[$i..$($i + 99)] 
}
```

Now if I got it right you want to join these 100 elements and surround them with  certain cahrachters ... this might work:

```
'"*' + ($Liste[$i..$($i + 99)] -join '*;*') + '*"'
```

Together it would be this:

```
$liste = Get-Content -Path 'C:\x\input.txt'
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Liste.Count; $i += 100) {
    '"*' + ($Liste[$i..$($i + 99)] -join '*;*') + '*"'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways, here's one of them...

First I would split array to chunks of 100 elements each, using this helper function:

```
Function Split-Array ($list, $count) {
    $aggregateList = @()

    $blocks = [Math]::Floor($list.Count / $count)
    $leftOver = $list.Count % $count
    for($i=0; $i -lt $blocks; $i++) {
        $end = $count * ($i + 1) - 1

        $aggregateList += @(,$list[$start..$end])
        $start = $end + 1
    }    
    if($leftOver -gt 0) {
        $aggregateList += @(,$list[$start..($end+$leftOver)])
    }

    $aggregateList    
}
```

For example to split your list into chunks of 100 do this:

```
$Splitted = Split-Array $liste -count 100
```

Then use foreach to iterate each chunk and join its elements for the pattern you need:

```
foreach ($chunk in $Splitted)
{
$Pattern = '"' + (($chunk | % {"*$_*"}) -join ";") + '"'
azcopy copy $source $target --include-pattern $Pattern --recursive=true
}
```